# Normalize each slice of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

How do I normalize each slice of a 3D matrix? I tried like this:

```
a=rand(1,100,3481);
a= (a - min(a)) ./ (max(a)-min(a)); %
```

By right each slice of matrix should ranges from `0` to `1`. But that is not the case, I don't find `1` in some of the slices. As I inspected, `min(a)` and `max(a)` returned the respective value in 3D. Thus it should be of no issue using the code above. Is there something I missed for 3D matrix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you assuming that every slice will have `1`?

Comment: I'm normalizing the values to `0` and `1`, shouldn't that give me `0` as minimum and `1` as maximum?

Comment: Every slice is not guaranteed to have the array’s minimum and maximum, which are the only values that are going to be 0 and 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to find the minimum and maximum values for each of those 2D slices and then we can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to do those operations in a vectorized manner with help from [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to let the singleton dims align properly to let `bsxfun` do its broadcasting job (or use `reshape` there).

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
mins = min(reshape(a,[],size(a,3)));
maxs = max(reshape(a,[],size(a,3)));
a_offsetted = bsxfun(@minus, a, permute(mins,[1,3,2]));
a_normalized = bsxfun(@rdivide, a_offsetted, permute(maxs-mins,[1,3,2]))
```

Sample input, output -

```
>> a
a(:,:,1) =
     2     8     2     2
     8     3     8     2
a(:,:,2) =
     8     1     1     5
     4     9     8     6
a(:,:,3) =
     7     9     3     5
     6     2     6     5
a(:,:,4) =
     9     3     4     9
     7     1     9     9
>> a_normalized
a_normalized(:,:,1) =
         0    1.0000         0         0
    1.0000    0.1667    1.0000         0
a_normalized(:,:,2) =
    0.8750         0         0    0.5000
    0.3750    1.0000    0.8750    0.6250
a_normalized(:,:,3) =
    0.7143    1.0000    0.1429    0.4286
    0.5714         0    0.5714    0.4286
a_normalized(:,:,4) =
    1.0000    0.2500    0.3750    1.0000
    0.7500         0    1.0000    1.0000
```

Comment: That's odd, if you try with `a=randi([1 10], [1 100 100])`, your code works. However if you try `a=rand(1,100,100)`, it doesn't works. This is very strange

Comment: @GregorIsack It worked for me for - `a=rand(1,100,100)`. Could you double check?

Comment: @GregorIsack How are you checking if its working or not? Don't do `==0` or `==1` thing. These are floating pt values. So, use a tolerance there. Something like : `tol = 1e-4;`. Then, do : `all(any(any(abs(a_normalized - 0) < tol,1),2))` and `all(any(any(abs(a_normalized - 1) < tol,1),2))`.

Comment: Sorry I took some times to double check. It seems like there's some 'memory lag' on my laptop. It works perfectly fine on my other laptop. I restarted my laptop it should be fine. Regarding the tolerance you mentioned, if I were to use the `find(a_normalized==1)`, that'll be an issue too?

Comment: @GregorIsack That `find(a_normalized==1)` won't be a great check. You need to check there's at least one `1` and at least one `0` in each slice, hence my earlier mentioned code comment.

Comment: I tries to retrieve the indexes of all the 1, guess I'm stuck with `find`?

Comment: @GregorIsack Use `find(abs(a_normalized - 1) < tol)` and then `ind2sub` to get corresponding indices along each of the three dims.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the extremely helpful answer and comments, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My option would be without reshaping as it is sometimes bit difficult to understand. I use min max with the dimension you want want to use for normalization with repmat to clone...:

```
a=rand(1,100,3481);

a_min2 = min(a,[],2);
a_max2 = max(a,[],2);
a_norm2 = (a - repmat(a_min2,[1 size(a,2) 1]) ) ./ repmat( (a_max2-a_min2),[1 size(a,2) 1]);
```

or if normalization on 3rd dim...

```
a_min3 = min(a,[],3);
a_max3 = max(a,[],3);
a_norm3 = (a - repmat(a_min3,[1 1 size(a,3)]) ) ./ repmat( (a_max3-a_min3),[1 1 size(a,3)]);
```